# Weighed Euclidean Distance to compare players

Tags: trigonometry

Good Day,

I am writing some code to compare how similar two players in a sport are.  Right now I am using three features: age (between 17.0 and 17.99), points/game (normally between 0.0 and 3.0) and height (155 - 206 cm).

I am playing with Euclidean Distance (did try Manhattan distance with less success).  The problem occurs when I include height as the closest players are those with the exact same height.  When it does it throws the ages and points/game values much farther apart than I wish (why this does makes intuitive sense to myself).

When I remove height, do the distance on the 2 remaining features, then only look at players who are within +/- 3 cm (an arbitrary value) I get what I perceive as much more natural results.

Is there a weighted euclidean distance technique I should be using instead that allows some diverging of values such as heights?

Comment: Let $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \ge 0$ be coefficients. Then a way to do Euclidean distance weighted is $f(x,y,z) = \sqrt{\alpha x^2 + \beta y^2 + \gamma z^2}$. In your case you want the height to be weighted less than the others so try something like $\alpha = 1, \beta = 10, \gamma = 10$ and play around with numbers till you find what you want.

Comment: You can also do some algebra with $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ as variables and solve some linear equations till you find the exact ones that fit your system. The general strategy is set $\alpha = 1$ and optimize over $\beta, \gamma$.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that in your units, height has a much larger range than the other two.  This makes it dominate, as players can easily be $10$ apart in height but no more than $\sqrt {10}$ apart in (age + goals).  From top to bottom, you have a range of $51$ in height, $1$ in age, and $3$ in goals.  If you measure height in meters, it will range from $1.55$ to $2.06$ and the range will only be $0.51$.  If you want the factors to have equal influence in the distance, you should scale them by the range.  Using the absolute range, you would use height/51, age, and goals/3.  If the distribution is not uniform, you could also look at the "width" of each distribution and divide by that.